# How to allow access to subdirectory in website using htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, 403-forbidden

I am wanting to create a seperate directory for my analytics program to function.

My website is www.loosebruce.co.uk and I want my directory to be accessible as

www.loosebruce.co.uk/analytics

The same way phpmyadmin is accessible with /phpmyadmin

I added the following line to .htaccess file but it is not letting me get into that folder

```
    # follow symlinks & disallow directory listing
# note: your hosting company might not allow these directives to be set. In that case,
# you should either find another hosting company (advised) or remove the line below.
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
DirectorySlash Off

# file etags (used when comparing local cached file to server file)
FileETag MTime Size

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # nice urls
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # forbidden folders
    RewriteRule .*\.gitignore - [F]
    RewriteRule composer\.json - [F]
    RewriteRule composer\.lock - [F]
    RewriteRule .*\.md - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Frontend/Cache/CachedTemplates - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Frontend/Cache/CompiledTemplates - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Frontend/Cache/Config - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Frontend/Cache/Locale/.*\.php - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Frontend/Cache/Logs - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Frontend/Cache/Navigation/.*\.php - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Frontend/Cache/Search - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Backend/Cache/CompiledTemplates - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Backend/Cache/Config - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Backend/Cache/Cronjobs - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Backend/Cache/Locale/.*\.php - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Backend/Cache/Logs - [F]
    RewriteRule src/Backend/Cache/Navigation - [F]
    RewriteRule src/analytics - [PT]

    #Rewriterule ^analytics/.*$ - [PT]
    #RewriteRule  ^$ /analytics/    [L]
    #RewriteRule  (.*) /analytics/$1 [L]

    # one url to rule them all
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.<domain>\.be [NC]
    # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !.*\.dev [NC]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.<domain>.be/$1 [R=301,L]

    # src dir should pass via the front controller
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(src|src\/)$
    RewriteRule . /index.php [NC,L]

    # handle urls
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . index.php [NC,L]

    # set environment variable to let PHP know that urls are being rewritten
    RewriteRule .* - [E=MOD_REWRITE:1]
</IfModule>

# file caching in browser
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png|svg|svgz|js|css|swf|ttf|otf|woff|eot)$">
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

# gzip on Apache 2
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml text/javascript text/css application/x-javascript application/xhtml+xml application/javascript

    # these browsers do not support deflate
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force
</IfModule>

# gzip on Apache 1
<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes

    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/javascript$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/xhtml+xml$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/xml$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/css$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/html$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/javascript$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/plain$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/xml$
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/

    # browser issues
    mod_gzip_item_exclude reqheader "User-agent: Mozilla/4.0[678]"
</IfModule>
```

What do I need to do?

Do I need a seperate .htaccess file in the /analytics directory?

Thanks

Comment: Where have you installed the analytics? If you install it in the directory you want it to be found, you should not have to do anything or much of anything at all. You should never need to create separate .htaccess files. You can of course. I have. But it is not necessary. You should be able to work from one single .htaccess file in the web space. What problems are you having specifically??

Comment: It is in /var/www/analytics

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing??

Comment: Try putting *DirectorySlash On* in the top of your .htaccess file. This should work.